# Solve $8^{x+1} = 32 \cdot\sqrt2$ without $\log$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation

I need help solving the equation $8^{x+1} = 32 \cdot\sqrt2$. The obvious answer is to use log, but that is reserved for the next section. The example given for this section of questions is:
\begin{align*}
4^x & = 8\\
(2^2)^x & = 2^3\\
2x & = 3\\
x & = \dfrac{3}{2}
\end{align*}

The example looks obvious and easy to solve, but I do not understand where you'd use this for my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that everything in sight is a power of $2$.

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  8^{x+1} &=& 32 \sqrt{2} \\
  (2^3)^{x+1} &=& 2^5\cdot 2^{1/2} \\
  2^{3(x+1)} &=& 2^{5 + 1/2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Since both sides are expressed as a power of the same base, we can set the exponents equal:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  3(x+1) &=& \frac{11}{2} \\
  x+1 &=& \frac{11}{6}\\
  x &=& \frac{11}{6} - 1 \\
  &=& \frac{5}{6}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: damn you were faster...

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I read through both of them :)

Answer (score 3):

$$
8^{x+1} = 32 \sqrt{2} 
$$
$$
8\times 8^x = 32 \sqrt{2}
$$
$$
8^x =2^{3x}= 4\sqrt{2}=2^2\times 2^{1/2}= 2^{2,5}
$$

$$
3x=2,5 \to x=\frac{5}{6}
$$